# Sesam DTL - Painful to create a complex json output

Tags: sesam

Currently, more and more pipes send out data in json. but it is painful to create a  complex json, because we have to use a lot of nested "dict" and "list". It is hard to read such dtls and image the output. Is there any better way to create json by dtl?

From my opinion, the best solution could be "using some template" and replace variables like jinja2 for xml and html, e.g.:

- ["add", "output_template", "{'id': $V(_id), 'name':
  $V(namespace:name), 'address': {'street': $V(namespace:street),
  'zipcode': $V(namespace:zipcode)}}"].
- ["json_render", _T.output_template, _S].

All $V variables will be replaced by the keys in "_S" or "_T".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your own template engine with DTL like this:

```
{
  "_id": "template",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": {
      "_id": "foo",
      "namespace:name": "Baard",
      "namespace:street": "Rødhettes vei 5",
      "namespace:zipcode": "1482"
    }
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["add", "output_template", {
          "name": "$V(namespace:name)",
          "address": {
            "street": "$V(namespace:street)",
            "zipcode": "$V(namespace:zipcode)"
          },
          "id": "$V(_id)"
        }],
        ["add", "output",
          ["apply", "template-engine", "_T.output_template"]
        ]
      ],
      "template-engine": [
        ["merge",
          ["map-dict", "_.",
            ["if",
              ["matches", "$V(*)", "_."],
              ["path",
                ["lstrip", "$V(",
                  ["rstrip", ")", "_."]
                ], "_R._S"],
              ["if",
                ["is-dict", "_."],
                ["apply", "template-engine", "_."]
              ]
            ], "_S."]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This gives you the following output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "foo",
    "output": {
      "address": {
        "street": "Rødhettes vei 5",
        "zipcode": "1482"
      },
      "id": "foo",
      "name": "Baard"
    },
    "output_template": {
      "address": {
        "street": "$V(namespace:street)",
        "zipcode": "$V(namespace:zipcode)"
      },
      "id": "$V(_id)",
      "name": "$V(namespace:name)"
    }
  }
]
```